# General question: Every user get disconnected from ethereum and now new user adds how will he get the entire data to his node?

Tags: go-ethereum

what if every user get disconnected from ethereum and new user adds how will he get the entire data

For example there are 10 persons in entire ethereum blockchain each having node and entire data is stored in there system while using go ethereum.. Now just imagine everyone got disconnected from the ethereum blockchain. Now 11th user try to connect for the first time then how will he get the data for entire ethereum blockchain? as there is no current active nodes?

Answer (score 2):

If every nodes go offline then there will be no blockchain network. So, new user/node would not be able to "connect" in the first place. The question how will he get the data is the secondary one.

You need an entry point to the public blockchain network. If all your peers are dead how can you get your transaction delivered to the network? In that case your chain is just a private blockchain with itself as an only node.

A blockchain network gets its value by being connected to other nodes (alive). A dead network is simply valueless and who would connect or transact to a dead network?

Therefore, a blockchain system also maintains some (multiple) static nodes called `bootnodes` which most probably are always alive and these bootnodes provide the data and list of peers to the new node.

Comment: If this has answered your question you can upvote it.